# How to change border width when focused

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, border

I want to change border width when focused.
My input box has 1px solid border.
When focused, It changes 2px different color solid border.
But there is 1px difference, so the div contains this input box changes its width 1px when focus.
I want to solve this problem.
I am a beginner in html and css so I am looking for your help.
Thank you.

```css
.contact-input {
  border: 1px solid #707070;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

.contact-label {
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
}

.contact-input input[type="text"] {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #707070;
  width: 40%;
}

.contact-input input[type="text"]:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #3AD6B1;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-input">
  <div class="contact-label">Name</div>
  <input class="w-50" type="text" placeholder="Your answer">
</div>
```

Comment: add an outline of 1px ? or a box-shadow?

Comment: use the :hover method

Comment: share some of your code so that the others can help you.

Comment: I edited my question by adding codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting the height of the contacts-input div to accommodate the increased border.

```css
.contact-input {
    border: 1px solid #707070;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 1.5rem;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
    padding: 1.5rem;
    height: 7.5rem;
}
```

Comment: I think I am picky, but how about auto height?

Comment: With auto height the same issue will occur. Better use box-sizing: border-box;
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Answer (score 5):

add `1px` of box-shadow

```css
.contact-input {
    border: 1px solid #707070;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 1.5rem;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
    padding: 1.5rem;
}
.contact-label {
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
}
.contact-input input[type="text"] {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #707070;
    width: 40%;
}
.contact-input input[type="text"]:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow:0 1px 0 #3AD6B1;
    border-color:#3AD6B1;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-input">
    <div class="contact-label">Name</div>
    <input class="w-50" type="text" placeholder="Your answer">
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer is useful. But I want to give animation when focus. Can you tell me some way?

Comment: @George what kind of animation?

Comment: Sorry for troubling you. I want for your help. I will give you some url. https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeqShwlxvjfykXzpXfImsjKLbIohPEcASRtsgdOvfTzAYqdjw/viewformPreview Here are animation I want to give.

Comment: I am sorry. I will tell you. I want the border fills start from middle to end points in 0.4 seconds.

Comment: @George like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48841015/8620333?

Comment: Yes, that's it. Can you give me your code?

Comment: @George you can find the code in the link there, it's also my answer ;)

Comment: The animated background covers the border. But the case of black border, the animated border cannot cover the black border and I don't think it looks good.

Comment: @George you may probably consider a different question to add more details about the animation you want. I am afraid that comments isn't the best way to handle this and we may easily get out of the scope of your initial question.