# Animation line out of the text

Tags: css

I have an animation made for a button but I readjusted it to normal text via this post here on stackoverlow, but now I have a problem. [The post mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48840743/how-to-animate-border-on-input-and-make-it-expand-from-center)

The animation line is perfect, but my text is far from the left edge and the animation works in this padding, that is, where there is no text it works, when in fact, I want it to stay only where there is actually text

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3a0M.png)

the red part is the one I want to remove

My code:

```html
        <div class="sidebar-content">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="support-sidebar-area">Suporte <span class="material-symbols-outlined arrow4">chevron_right</span></a>
                    <ul class="itens-support-hub">
                        <li><a href="#" class="content-sidebar-area">Teste</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="content-sidebar-area">Teste</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="content-sidebar-area">Teste</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="content-sidebar-area">Teste</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="content-sidebar-area">Teste</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
```

```css
.content-sidebar-area{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Confortaa;
    line-height: 25px;
    background:
            linear-gradient(#151400 0 0) bottom / 0% 2px no-repeat
            #71c1ec;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.content-sidebar-area:hover {
    background-size: 100% 2px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Try using margin instead of padding, borders and backgrounds tend to follow the padding on the element.